# $2\,000\,000 = \frac{1}{1.1^5} \cdot \sum_{t=1}^{10} \frac{e}{1.7^t}$

Tags: summation, economics

Let

$$2\,000\,000 = \frac{1}{1.1^5} \cdot \sum_{t=1}^{10} \frac{e}{1.7^t}$$

($e$ is not Euler’s number here)

Apparently $e$ is $399\,382.63$ but how can one find that out?

If I multiply $20\,000\,000$ with $1.1^5$ I get $3\,221\,020$.
But then? I can't multiply with $1.07^t$ because it's in the sum.

Comment: Do you know the sum of a geometric progression?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, but I don't know how to apply it

Comment: I suggest you write down the formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression, and compare it to your problem.  I feel sure you'll see how it applies.

Comment: I obtain $e=458\,600.78$.

Comment: Please note that in the anglophone, our decimal marker is `.` and in math this is especially critical given the notational importance of commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is of the form $a=eb \sum_{t=1}^{10}c^t.$

We have $\sum_{t=1}^{10}c^t=c \frac{1-c^{10}}{1-c}.$

Thus

$$a=ebc \frac{1-c^{10}}{1-c}.$$

$a,b$ and $c$ are given, hence

$$e=\frac{a}{bc \frac{1-c^{10}}{1-c}}.$$

Comment: $\sum_{t=1}^{10}c^t=c \sum_{t=0}^{9}c^t= c\frac{1-c^{10}}{1-c}.$

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that you already took $c$ out. I've deleted my comment

Comment: Thanks Fred, but it's still unclear for me. 
I tried inserting the values but get a different result.
Can oyu tell me what values you use for $a,b,c$?

Comment: $a=2 000 000, b=\frac{1}{1,15}, c= \frac{1}{1,7}.$